# Authentication with loopback and angular

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I am attempting to perform authentication with loopbackJS as a backend provider. After following the documentation on loopback's doc site I'm still receiving an "Unknown Provider error".

Here is the following code I've written so far.

**Home View**

```
<form class="centered" ng-controller="UserController as user">
<div class ="form-group">
    <label for="exampleEmail">Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="{{user.usernames.email}}">
    <label for="examplePassword">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="{{user.usernames.password}}">
    <p>{{user.description}}</p>
    <button class="button" ng-show="user.usernames.signin" ng-submit="login()">login</a> </button>
</div>
</form>
```

**Auth Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app')
app.controller('UserController', ['$scope','AuthService', '$state', function($scope, AuthService, $state){
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'foo@bar.com',
      password: 'foobar'
    };

        $scope.login = function() {
      AuthService.login($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
        .then(function() {
          $state.go('success');
        });
    };


}]);
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Todo Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<header ng-include="'views/header.html'"></header>
<body>


<ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/auth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/auth.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/lb-services.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in order to provide as much detail into the problem as possible here is a look at the errors presently in my console.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation you have followed ? From what I guess, they either give you the code for AuthService provider of which dependency you inject in your controller or they expect you to code one of your own. If they give it, did you include its script in your HTML ? And did you add the corresponding dependency to your app's module ?

Comment: Hey Thanks for the comment. I actually just found the answer (via trial and error) on the angular docs. I guess I forgot to provide a service function inside of my auth.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `AuthService` is some service you wrote yourself. You should use instead the utility provided by strongloop to generate the service from your server's models.

Authentication with loopback + angular is pretty straightforward like that.

1. Generate angular services from loopback server by running `lb-ng . ./client/js/lb-services.js` inside your server's root folder.
2. Then in angular, call `MyUser.login({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'foobar'})`
3. Done. If credentials are correct, the user will be authenticated for any further request (basically, the service memorizes the connection token, and sets it in the `Authorization` header each time a new request is made against your REST api).
4. Eventually, you may be interested in calling `MyUser.isAuthenticated()` to make your page behave differently if the user is, well, authenticated.

This is all documented [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK)

Answer (score 0):

You are using AuthService, which is user created service. It is abstraction over lb-services.js of loopback. You have to generate lb-services.js using lb command line.

Loopback angularjs Authentication : Login and registration
Steps:

1. Create new loopback project.
2. Generate lb-services.js and use it in angularjs project.
3. Use User.login() for login, User.create() for registration and User.isAuthenticated() to check user is login or not.

Best tutorial for [loopback angularjs authentication](http://www.thenextfact.com/loopback-authentication-loopback-angularjs-user-registration-and-login-example-and-tutorial/)